# Notepad++ Deleting specific text

Tags: notepad++

I got the following text in my text file:

```
Points = 200 | Code = ABXD829SH2
Points = 300 | Code = WBSD829SH2
Points = 240 | Code = SBXD829SH2
Points = 250 | Code = GBXD829SH2
```

How can I delete in notepad++ anything before the code begins?
So this should be deleted "Points = 200 | Code = ". Only the code should remain.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can apply regex in replace :

Find what:

```
Points = (\d+) \| Code =
```

Replace with:

```
(nothing)
```

[image: Apply Regex]

Result:

```
ABXD829SH2
WBSD829SH2
SBXD829SH2
GBXD829SH2
```

Comment: I can accept it in 8 minutes, I will do it then! Thank you mate!

Answer (score 0):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `^.+Code =`
- Replace with: `LEAVE EMPTY`
- **CHECK** *Match case*
- **CHECK** *Wrap around*
- **CHECK** *Regular expression*
- **UNCHECK** `. matches newline`
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
^               # beginning of line
  .+            # 1 or more any character but newline
  Code =        # literally
```

**Screen capture (before):**

[image]

**Screen capture (after):**

[image]